# Unable to sign using gnupg_sign in php

Tags: php, gnupg

I'm playing around with HSBC's sandbox and I need to encrypt and sign a payload before sending.

HSBC has provided me with a pre generated keys for the sanbox so I have:

- client private
- client public
- HSBC public

and a passphrase of "1password"

I've got (GnuPG) 2.2.19 running on my box, and with php I've imported all 3 keys with gnupg_import.

Now if I run gnupg_keyinfo I get: (I've changed the names/email/uid to hide my business)

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [disabled] => 
            [expired] => 
            [revoked] => 
            [is_secret] => 
            [can_sign] => 1
            [can_encrypt] => 1
            [uids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Client Payment Notification
                            [comment] => 
                            [email] => tomw@client.co.uk
                            [uid] => Client_ Payment Notification 
                            [revoked] => 
                            [invalid] => 
                        )

                )

            [subkeys] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fingerprint] => 70A91F261D23DDDE77CB52BE61BE8D97497C9424
                            [keyid] => 61BE8D97497C9424
                            [timestamp] => 1675936132
                            [expires] => 0
                            [is_secret] => 
                            [invalid] => 
                            [can_encrypt] => 
                            [can_sign] => 1
                            [disabled] => 
                            [expired] => 
                            [revoked] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [fingerprint] => 34CA88A208742E3DAB6850040C1088250E620B25
                            [keyid] => 0C1088250E620B25
                            [timestamp] => 1675936132
                            [expires] => 0
                            [is_secret] => 
                            [invalid] => 
                            [can_encrypt] => 1
                            [can_sign] => 
                            [disabled] => 
                            [expired] => 
                            [revoked] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [disabled] => 
            [expired] => 
            [revoked] => 
            [is_secret] => 
            [can_sign] => 1
            [can_encrypt] => 1
            [uids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HSBC-Sandbox-Public
                            [comment] => 
                            [email] => help@mail.develop.hsbc.com
                            [uid] => HSBC-Sandbox-Public 
                            [revoked] => 
                            [invalid] => 
                        )

                )

            [subkeys] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fingerprint] => 37518BFC71C9B490C9980F489E459E50958DA76C
                            [keyid] => 9E459E50958DA76C
                            [timestamp] => 1668584185
                            [expires] => 0
                            [is_secret] => 
                            [invalid] => 
                            [can_encrypt] => 
                            [can_sign] => 1
                            [disabled] => 
                            [expired] => 
                            [revoked] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [fingerprint] => 0F973BB7DBF26B8EA2A05299251305CBA700420A
                            [keyid] => 251305CBA700420A
                            [timestamp] => 1668584185
                            [expires] => 0
                            [is_secret] => 
                            [invalid] => 
                            [can_encrypt] => 1
                            [can_sign] => 
                            [disabled] => 
                            [expired] => 
                            [revoked] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

From here I can also encrypt a message using the HSBC public key by doing

```
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_addencryptkey($res,"0F973BB7DBF26B8EA2A05299251305CBA700420A");
$enc = gnupg_encrypt($res, "just a test");
echo $enc;
```

and the output is

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- hQGMAyUTBcunAEIKAQv/VhNCgR5GQU/xYxYF5dzLh5s2oegX4ARZ0pg6PeXREsva FXh/W4hkJFb4jSdLCDSY8eerzII7AyIDrsuasG25tsfAZ1FVJhs0y5TPEqSNpLuV CG0nt9s0CFiJUWyF3gwYipE73OaMbHJxYGZy1zQLpLd4L92rhaUS2pC6Xq1SLydp hz/CWoROwxpuGekaaVX015EeFhaCeZa0K/yleTP05dbBJPaYKwi/4z5QVBMlpYwf K/nDkq8b0HG+RF6+T99GzXldp7wxBPSIY65Ft5iC9cL9vTcEFnHtiglyXziwBgNV KMLYyaf8iH2AYKLwLd31XRswHAf+E6PLMRwqoDJg639h8G8oNvYJrGJf77e95FI/ LdAzwb8SpOTAadgfysLxK0pkRgFFRxAC0ykbjjDNJVPiOqw7GfEiM4hNvnFhvmNX elfYjQCLCeDakZFKVobkkQYDyUybci1ItFvIN5fqgwIzLF+CBqUvcnpROqGkbONR hc30VqDYX1B2aMLABHGB0kYBTUzkcQl3q6nNxCYj6ib3g/6Rk8u6y++4FKQYuO3Q TbPMF7Rl4UKAGMywQEYXiWOUoEFAD49vVisYfuIk01wBfgmd/ZHu =J+Ry -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

But the part I fail at, is the signing. I tried gnupg_encryptsign with the follwing code

```
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_addencryptkey($res,"0F973BB7DBF26B8EA2A05299251305CBA700420A"); // HSBC PUBLIC
gnupg_addsignkey($res,"70A91F261D23DDDE77CB52BE61BE8D97497C9424", "1password"); // CLIENT PRIVTE
$enc = gnupg_encryptsign($res, "Tom Test");
echo $enc;

echo "<h1>Errors</h1>";
print_r(gnupg_geterror($res));
```

and I get **encrypt-sign failed**

So I tried just signing with without encruption and

```
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_addsignkey($res,"70A91F261D23DDDE77CB52BE61BE8D97497C9424", "1password"); //  CLIENT PRIVTE
$signed = gnupg_sign($res, "just a test");
echo $signed;
echo "<h1>Errors</h1>";
print_r(gnupg_geterror($res));
```

and that gives me **data signing failed**

So to rule out a few things I've also tried the following.

- tried to sign leaving the passphrase blank - **Failed**
- set up a new set of keys with the passprase "test", tried to sign again - **Failed**
- made another set of keys with NO passprase and tried to sign - **Success**

So why is it that I can never sign if I use a passphrase?